# How to get the value of related content of a task list in sharepoint 2010 C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We know that, task list of workflow has a column named `Related content`. How can I get the value of `Related Content` of specific task item. I have tried following way but unsuccessful.

```
var campaignTaskList = currentWeb.Lists["CampaignTask"].Items;
var currentUserTaskList = (from SPListItem taskItem in campaignTaskList
                            let assignTo = new SPFieldUserValue(taskItem.Web, taskItem["Assigned To"].ToString())
                             where assignTo.User.Name == currentWeb.CurrentUser.Name
                             select taskItem).ToList();

     foreach (SPListItem workflowTaskItem in currentUserTaskList)
          {
             var item =  workflowTaskItem["Related Content"].ToString();
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Related Content` field declaration:

```
<Field ID="{58DDDA52-C2A3-4650-9178-3BBC1F6E36DA}"
    Name="WorkflowLink"
    SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
    StaticName="WorkflowLink"
    Group="_Hidden"
    Type="URL"
    DisplayName="$Resources:core,LinkField;"
    ReadOnly="TRUE"
    Sealed="TRUE">
</Field>
```

### How to get Related Content field value

By [field Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.aspX):

```
var relContent = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowLink];
```

By field name:

```
var relContent = item["WorkflowLink"];
```